# Creating first campaign with facebook marketing api python sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to learn facebook marketing api with python and i want to create my first facebook campaign with it.

So i typed in python shell:

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects

my_app_id = '<APP_ID>'
my_app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>'
my_access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)


from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign

campaign = Campaign(parent_id='act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>')
campaign.update({
    Campaign.Field.name: 'My First Campaign',
    Campaign.Field.objective: '<LINK_CLICKS>',
})

campaign.remote_create(params={
    'status': Campaign.Status.paused,
})
print(campaign)
```

where i relaced:
`<APP_ID>` with my APP id
`<APP_SECRET>` with my app secret
`<ACCESS_TOKEN>` with token i created for ads_management
`<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>` with my add account id

But i've got error...

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\utils\api_utils.py", line 30
    warnings.warn(message)
UserWarning: value of objective might not be compatible.  Expect objective_enum;  got <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/G/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/fb-api-test.py", line 18, in <module>
    'status': Campaign.Status.paused,
  File "C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\adobjects\abstractcrudobject.py", line 290, in remote_create
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\api.py", line 658, in execute
    api_version=self._api_version,
  File "C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookads\api.py", line 325, in call
    raise fb_response.error()
facebookads.exceptions.FacebookRequestError: 

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  POST
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_<ad_account_id>/campaigns
  Params:  {'status': 'PAUSED', 'objective': '<LINK_CLICKS>', 'name': 'My First Campaign'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "fbtrace_id": "E...",
        "code": 190
      }
    }
```

What else should i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this page to generate your access token, especially via graph api explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#manually-getting-access-tokens

You should also change your objective to one of these:
APP_INSTALLS, BRAND_AWARENESS, CONVERSIONS, EVENT_RESPONSES, LEAD_GENERATION, LINK_CLICKS, LOCAL_AWARENESS, OFFER_CLAIMS, PAGE_LIKES, POST_ENGAGEMENT, PRODUCT_CATALOG_SALES, REACH, VIDEO_VIEWS